# Ms SQL server - left join which returns multiple rows display as columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by, left-join

I have the following SQL...

```
    SELECT 'TESTPRODUCT' AS Product_Code,Colours.Name FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT col.Product_Id,colo.Name from ProductColour colo INNER JOIN
        Product__Colour col on colo.ProductColour_Id = col.ProductColour_Id
        group by col.Product_Id,colo.Name
    )   Colours
    ON p.Product_Id = Colours.Product_Id

  WHERE Product_Code = 'TESTPRODUCT'
```

My problem is that it returns...

```
    Product_Code    Name
    TESTPRODUCT     Black
    TESTPRODUCT     Blue
    TESTPRODUCT     Silver
```

What I need it to do is..

```
    Product_Code    Name1    Name2    Name3
    TESTPRODUCT     Black    Blue     Silver
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: That's known as a dynamic pivot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745076/507